# Смена названия загружаемой картинки в PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, я нашел способ как добавлять картинку через PHP в свой каталог в папке с проектом,
здесь я посмотрел как это реализовать (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) .
И вот в чем вопрос, можно ли как то изменять название загружаемого файла? Так как я например хочу
потом его высветлять на своем сайте,  то мне нужно что бы картинка была нужного мне имени, которое
я например буду указывать как id поста к которому она будет прикреплена, буду раз за любые  подсказки :)

Comment: _можно ли как то изменять название загружаемого файла?_ - можно

Comment: Спасибо, рад за подсказку

Comment: Если посмотреть функцию [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php) можно заметить что 2 параметр это то, куда сам файл сохранять - там есть имя файла, его можете менять. 2+2=? - нужна помощь? Данный случай не сложней

Comment: @VladyslavVerong после загрузки можно переименовать файл с помощью 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: @InDevX, $target_file оно показывает как папку + имя (например: uploads/screen.png), а как мне разделить это?

Comment: @VladyslavVerong там в самом начале определяется переменная `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`, замените `_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])` на необохдимое имя